# Get hostname while on Dropwizard service run method

Tags: java, jersey, swagger, dropwizard

I am trying to use dropwizard + swagger to have a rest api...and it's documentation.

Problem I found is that swagger requires to set a "basePath" property when initialising the resource that will serve the documentation:

```
@Override
public void run(MyServiceConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
    ...
    ...
    // Set the swagger config options
    SwaggerConfig config = ConfigFactory.config();
    config.setApiVersion("1.0.0");
    config.setBasePath("http://localhost:9090/api");
```

I can get the port and the rootpath from the configuration parameter.
But is there any way to actually get the protocol + hostname while I am at the service run method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a relative path like this:

```java
config.setBasePath(".." + environment.getApplicationContext().getContextPath());
```

Comment: It actually worked setting 
    config.setBasePath("../")

On swagger ui calls are made to:

http://myhost.com:9090/../something/1

which looks kinda hackish but works...